# Meaning of "Object" in James Madison's 1783 Letter

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of **object** in the last paragraph ? Please divulge the steps and thought processes behind your deduction. I'm vacillating between [these two](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/object?q=object), the first of which I'm well acquainted with:

1. a person or thing to which a specified action or feeling is directed:
2. a goal or purpose

> [Princeton, October 16, 1783.](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=james%20madison%20Recipient%3A%22Hamilton%2C%20Alexander%22&s=1111311113&r=4)
>
> Dear Sir :
>
> Your favor of the sixth of July, by some singular ill luck, 
>   never found its way to my hands till yesterday evening.
>
> The only part that now needs attention, is a request that I 
>   would answer the following question : " What appeared to be 
>   my ideas and disposition respecting the removal of Congress : 
>   did I appear to wish to hasten it, or did I not rather show a 
>   strong disposition to procrastinate it?" If this request had been 
>   received at the time it ought, it might have been answered as 
>   fully as you then wished. Even after the delay which has taken 
>   place, my recollection enables me, with certainty, to witness, 
>   that the uniform strain of your sentiments, as they appeared, 
>   both from particular conversations with myself, and incidental 
>   ones with others in my presence, was opposed to the removal of 
>   Congress, except in the last necessity; that when you finally 
>   yielded to the measure, it appeared to be more in compliance 
>   with the peremptory expostulations of others than with any dis- 
>   position of your own mind ; and that after the arrival of Con- 
>   gress at Princeton, your conversation showed that you reviewed 
>   the removal, rather with regret than with pleasure.
>
> Perhaps this obedience to your wishes may be too late to 
>   answer the original **object** of them. But I could not omit such 
>   an opportunity of testifying the esteem and regard with which I 
>   am
>
> Your obedient servant,
>
> J. Madison, Jb.
>   To the Hon. Alexander Hamilton, Esq.

Comment: There are two definitions in general reference here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/object. Do you think you can understand the meaning in context if one of these are used?

Comment: @Jim: The trouble is that I think both to fit here, when really  they don't? How to distinguish which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the second, the "goal or purpose".

In Madison's response being delayed, he may no longer adequately serve the goal or purpose for which the original correspondence was made.

It will clearly still address the person, since the two people involved are Madison himself (clearly still alive) and Hamilton (clearly still alive), so it can't be too late to answer the object in that sense.

Comment: It might be helpful to add that "answer" here means "to serve, to satisfy".